# i am getting this error

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I`m getting this error:

```
07-21 11:05:21.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1329): 
       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
07-21 11:05:21.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1329): 
       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
```

How do i deal with this kind of error?
here is my code:

```
try {
  List<Address> addresses = mGeocoder.getFromLocation(gettextLat, gettextLong, 1);
  Log.e("TAG", addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + 
        addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + 
        addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2));
  String myAddress = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + 
        addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
  textAddresss.setText(myAddress);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @Reimeus: you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ArrayList` is empty. Check its `size` before attempting to access it

```
List<Address> addresses = mGeocoder.getFromLocation(gettextLat, gettextLong, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) {
    Log.e("TAG", addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
            + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1)
            + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2));
    String myAddress = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
            + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1)
            + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
    textAddresss.setText(myAddress);
}
```